# How to play background music in a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, deployment, background-music

So I've made a small text-based game in C# but I'd like some music to it, I have tried this:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = "c:\PathToMusic\..music.wav";
player.Play();
```

Which worked, but when I build my application to a .exe file it's not included so when the other person does not have that specific sound in the specific folder it won't work.
I have added the file to my Solution Explorer but have no idea what that file location is called.

Comment: Build it as a resource.

Comment: Tried it, gets me an error that says FileNotFound, which makes sense i guess because i never told my code where the file in the Solution Explorer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution :

### Add music file into Solution

Project -> Add Existing Item... -> Add your .wav file.

### Set the file to `Copy always`

1. Click the music file in Solution Explorer.
2. In the Properties panel, set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`.
3. Also, set `Build Action` to `Content`.

This will make Visual Studio always copying the music file into the output directory (e.g. Debug folder).

### Use this code

```
using System.Media;  

SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\yourmusic.wav";
player.Play();
```

Comment: This gives me this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.dll"

Comment: Nvm, after changing the music file back from Resource to Content it worked! Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1):

First add your resource. Then in the Solution Explorer click on it. In the Properties Panel, set Build Action to resource.

Next access it like this:

```
player.Stream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.gameMusic);
```